# Removing A Function from an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, delegates

I have an array of functions that I'm trying to use like a delegate event in c#.

I push a function to the array, and when the array loops over the functions it will get called.

Problem is I'm having trouble removing the function once I'm done with it, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Here is my code. I'm totally up for a different method of doing this, I'm fairly new to JS/JQ so this is what I came up with.

```js
var MouseMoveFunctions = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    //Create the event to call our functions.
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        CallMouseMoveFunctions(e);
    });
   
});

function CallMouseMoveFunctions(e){  
    //Only continue if there is atleast 1 function in the array.
    if(MouseMoveFunctions.length == 0) return;
    
    //Call each function in the array.
    for(var i = 0; i < MouseMoveFunctions.length;i++){
        MouseMoveFunctions[i](e);
    }
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    //Add the TrackMouse function to the array.
    MouseMoveFunctions.push(function(event){TrackMouse(event)});
});




var mX = 0;
var mY = 0;

function TrackMouse(e){
     mX = e.pageX;
     mY = e.pageY;    
    
    var index = MouseMoveFunctions.indexOf(function(event){TrackMouse(event)});
    alert(index); //Always coming up -1, so it isn't getting removed
    
    //Try and remove the function if it exists, just for now so I know its working
    if(index != -1){
    MouseMoveFunctions.splice(index);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> //Always coming up -1, so it isn't getting removed

You always get `-1` because you're passing a unique function object to `.indexOf()`, so it can't already be in the array. The anonymous function that you pushed into the array has no other reference, so you can't remove it by reference.

Because you're pushing and removing a function that simply passes along the event argument, you can instead push the function itself.

```
MouseMoveFunctions.push(TrackMouse);
```

Then you'll be able to successfully find it if you look for the same function by identity.

```
var index = MouseMoveFunctions.indexOf(TrackMouse);
```

Note that if you put the same function into the array more than once, you'll need to remove it separately for each time.

Also, as noted by Scott, you need to provide the number of items to remove.

---

A better solution would be to use a `Set` instead of an Array. Also, you can get rid of those `.ready()` handlers.

```
var MouseMoveFunctions = new Set();

//Create the event to call our functions.
$(document).mousemove(CallMouseMoveFunctions);

function CallMouseMoveFunctions(e){  
    //Only continue if there is atleast 1 function in the array.
    if(MouseMoveFunctions.size == 0) return;

    //Call each function in the set.
    for(const fn of MouseMoveFunctions) {
        fn(e);
    }
}

//Add the TrackMouse function to the array.
MouseMoveFunctions.add(TrackMouse);

var mX = 0;
var mY = 0;

function TrackMouse(e){
     mX = e.pageX;
     mY = e.pageY;    

     MouseMoveFunctions.delete(TrackMouse);
}
```

Comment: That's so weird, I was trying to pass the function on its own earlier and it wasn't working. I guess something else was wrong with it.

I did not know that there was a set, is it similar to c# list?

Thanks Pete.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a 1 as the second argument to [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to tell it to remove 1 element at the index position you provided as the first argument.

```
.splice(index, 1)
```

Comment: Its actually not required, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: @LittlrRain if it’s omitted, all elements from the index to the end of the array will be deleted, not just the one at the index.

Comment: Ahh ok, I guess the way I was using it wasn't affected. Thanks